# How to Stop Airport jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know how I can stop this Plugin after it unscrambles the text? I love the animation, but I'd like it to stop rather than repeating. Here is a link http://www.caitmizzi.com/Untitled-1.html

Here is the JQuery

```
    (function($){ 
     $.fn.extend({  
         airport: function(array) {

            var self = $(this);
            var chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g',' ','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','-'];
            var longest = 0;
            var items = items2 = array.length;

            function pad(a,b) { return a + new Array(b - a.length + 1).join(' '); }

            $(this).empty();

            while(items--)
                if(array[items].length > longest) longest = array[items].length;

            while(items2--)
                array[items2] = pad(array[items2],longest);

            spans = longest;
            while(spans--)
                $(this).prepend("<span class='c" + spans + "'></span>");


            function testChar(a,b,c,d){
                if(c >= array.length)
                    setTimeout(function() { testChar(0,0,0,0); }, 1000);                
                else if(d >= longest)
                    setTimeout(function() { testChar(0,0,c+1,0); }, 1000);
                else {
                    $(self).find('.c'+a).html((chars[b]==" ")?"&nbsp;":chars[b]);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if(b > chars.length)
                            testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
                        else if(chars[b] != array[c].substring(d,d+1).toLowerCase())
                            testChar(a,b+1,c,d);
                        else
                            testChar(a+1,0,c,d+1);
                    }, 20);
                }
            }

            testChar(0,0,0,0);
        } 
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

This is the function

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
                $('#Entry').airport(['caitmizzi']);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(c >= array.length)
    setTimeout(function() { testChar(0,0,0,0); }, 1000);                
else if(d >= longest)
     setTimeout(function() { testChar(0,0,c+1,0); }, 1000);
else
```

To:

```
if(c >= array.length || d >= longest){
}  
else
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VPWyQ/

Comment: Thank You! I had tried .stop  to no avail. But this is perfect.

Comment: It is not a animation, the plugin sets new timeouts, which you need to stop after it's done, or don't call any timeouts like above.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option : `loop: {Boolean}`

Default: true
Choose whether to stop at the end of your array values or keep looping through.

Source : http://seancoker.com/projects/airport/